# Windows 10/ubuntu dual install goes only to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Running windows 10 on a ASUS MOTHERBOARD 64 BIT, lotsa disk storage, as well as memory. I was running Ubuntu on a laptop by itself and thought it might be good running dual boot on the Windows machine. I installed it, following the path to have it live in concert with windows.  When it rebooted, it went right to Windows as if there was no other option. Do I need to modify my boot table or do some other special thing to make the system give me a choice of which OS to run?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying you are installing Linux next to Windows. Just to confirm it's not the other way around.

**Changing Boot Order**

1. When your computer first turns on you need to press the F2 or F12 button (this depends on your computer). F2 worked for my Dell Inspiron. This should open a menu with advanced options. Use left and right arrow keys to navigate tabs to the one that says 'Boot' or something similar.
2. Once you're in this menu, you will have to change the order of your boot options. Your computer may be using BIOS or UEFI. If you have 'secure boot' turned on, you will need to turn it off to change the order of your boot options.
3. Press the enter key on the format you are using (BIOS or UEFI) and use the F5 and F6 arrow keys to move the Linux system above the Windows boot option. Save your changes with F10 and you should be good to go! Now grub should load when your computer turns on and give you an option of which system you want.

Note: Some of these keys may be different on your system but there should be a little 'table' on the bottom of your screen that tells you what each button or key does.

Edit: If this answer was helpful please accept it. Otherwise let me know what went wrong and I can help you figure it out.